# Getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource using chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to make a chrome extension. I referred the [chrome extensions documentaion](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission) which says that:

> By adding hosts or host match patterns (or both) to the permissions
>   section of the manifest file, the extension can request access to
>   remote servers outside of its origin.

So, in order to access data from http://www.codechef.com/ I added the following permission to my `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Testing Extension.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": ["http://www.codechef.com/"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Test",
    "default_popup": "test.html"
  }
}
```

I wrote a simple script to get data from the above mentioned website:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.codechef.com/", true);

console.log(xhr.status); // 0
console.log(xhr.readyState); // 1
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText); // empty
    document.getElementById("para").innerText = xhr.responseText;
  }
}
xhr.send();
```

But when I execute the script I get the following error: 
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.codechef.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.`

PS : I went through other questions with similar problem on SO. In most of the questions either op didn't include permissions inside their `manifest.json` or permissions was not located as an independent entry which is not the case here.

Comment: Your origin should not be `localhost`, are you sure you're executing this from the context of the extension?

Comment: @Xan I'm sorry but I didn't get what you meant by 'context of extension'.

Comment: Where in your extension's code you have that XHR call?

Comment: It's present in a separate JavaScript file which is included inside `test.html`.

Comment: And you are loading it as an extension popup, not separately for testing?

Comment: Currently I am testing it in my browser.

Comment: And that's why it doesn't work. You're not loading it in an extension, therefore your manifest and special permissions granted therein don't apply. To test/debug popups, right-click your extension's button and select "Inspect Popup"

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. But I am still getting the same error. Only the origin has now changed to my chrome extension.

Comment: Did you reload your extension after adding the new permissions in the manifest file?

Comment: @RobW Thanks. It was the problem. I should have tried that before posting it here.